# WireGuard full tunnel blocks Internet access

Tags: vpn, subnet, wireguard, nftables

Thanks for even clicking on my question !

So, I have an R-Pi, and I installed WireGuard on it (I am NOT using PiVPN; I tried, but it wasn't working at all). I also have PiHole installed.

I have been following the [WireGuard guide of the PiHole docs](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/wireguard/overview/) because I was sure that the 2 services would coexist well.

Everything went to plan, no need for troubleshooting...

This config, from what it seems, routes my DNS requests through PiHole (as it's supposed to), because if I blacklist a domain, and try to go to it once connected to the VPN, it doesn't work (but does if it's whitelisted). This also allows me to ping devices on the server's LAN (more specifically on its main Ethernet's subnet); I cannot ping using the hostname though, weirdly enough...

So here is the config server side :

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.100.0.1/24, fd08:4711::1/64
ListenPort = 50009
PrivateKey = <myprivatekey>
PostUp = nft add table ip wireguard; nft add chain ip wireguard wireguard_chain {type nat hook postrouting priority src>
PostDown = nft delete table ip wireguard; nft delete table ip6 wireguard
# apparently according to the PiHole docs, I must use nft and not iptables for Raspbian 11.

[Peer] #mypc
PublicKey = <mypublickey>
PresharedKey = <presharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.100.0.2/32, fd08:4711::2/128
```

And now client side :

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <myprivatekey>
Address = 10.100.0.2/32, fd08:4711::2/128
DNS = 10.100.0.1 #ip of server wich has PiHole on it

[Peer]
PublicKey = <mypublickey>
PresharedKey = <mypresharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.100.0.1/32, fd08:4711::1/128, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = <mydomainname>:50009
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

So that's all well and good (considering I was going to write I had DNS leaks, but just ran a test, and it seems fine !). Just one question here (not the main question) : are my DNS requests encrypted with this system ?

But now I would like a full tunnel, where all my traffic goes through my server, so that my IP is masked, and I can access securely some SMB shares (I have configured SFTP, but in case it breaks, I want a backup way to access my files).

So many tutorials (including the PiHole docs) said  to set `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`... Which I did, buuuuut... I instantly lose internet connection... Could it be a firewall issue ? If so, where : server side or client side ?

If I nslookup any domain, it won't resolve, even though my server (with PiHole on it) is specified as DNS server for the tunnel...

Here is the server config for that (no change):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.100.0.1/24, fd08:4711::1/64
ListenPort = 50009
PrivateKey = <myprivatekey>
PostUp = nft add table ip wireguard; nft add chain ip wireguard wireguard_chain {type nat hook postrouting priority src>
PostDown = nft delete table ip wireguard; nft delete table ip6 wireguard
# apparently according to the PiHole docs, I must use nft and not iptables for Raspbian 11.

[Peer] #mypc
PublicKey = <mypublickey>
PresharedKey = <presharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.100.0.2/32, fd08:4711::2/128
```

And here is client side :

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <myprivatekey>
Address = 10.100.0.2/32, fd08:4711::2/128
DNS = 10.100.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <mypublickey>
PresharedKey = <mypresharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <mydomainname>:50009
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

On the WireGuard Windows app, I can unselect "Block untunneled traffic", which changes `AllowedIPs` to `0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1`. Doesn't change or help anything, but just thought I'd mention it...

I really don't understand, been struggling on this for 5 hours now... Pretty desperate...

Thanks for even getting this far into the huge read !

Silloky

Comment: I'm going to look into this : https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/11/14/wireguard-vpn-typical-setup/

Comment: Just an idea: Did you replace the `eth0` by your "real" interface (like `enp2s0`) in the PostUp/PostDown steps? You may want to open a discussion on their https://discourse.pi-hole.net/ because there will be many users with the same setup as you have/want it.

Comment: @MrD : A comment after so long !!!!!! I bypassed the issue by using an installer script from GitHub, but I still don't understand why it wasn't working...

Comment: Could you put a link to the installer script and/or your config *after* the installer script so future users finding this here can see what the difference is/was. Maybe the Pi-hole docs are missing a step or you have overseen one.

Comment: @MrD Posted the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, just to put things clear : this isn't a solution, it's bypass.

I finally decided to use this GitHub script : https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install

I think the issus was something to do with resolv.conf but I am not sure. The pihole docs actually express that problem in the troubleshooting section :
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93EpO.png)

So if there are any folks out there with the same problem as me, feel free to use the link (i am NOT sponsored by @angristan...)

Silloky